# datepicker doesn't work after load page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

here is the my code,in my home page there is a button to load this page, it is done by                  using jquery `$("#content").load(site_url);`  like this. but this date picker doesn't work

```
 </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>


    $(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });
    });
    </script>
    <div id="content">
    <form>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker">
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: any error in browser console?

Comment: are using asp.net update panel? else it's working fine with me

Comment: GET http://localhost/FinanceManagementSystem/index.php/login/styles.css

Comment: Local host not Works man. Put the code in any online editor

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function VM696:11
(anonymous function) VM696:11
j jquery.min.js:2
k.add jquery.min.js:2
m.fn.ready jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous function) VM696:2
(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:2
m.extend.globalEval jquery.min.js:2
m.fn.extend.domManip jquery.min.js:3
m.fn.extend.append jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:3
m.access jquery.min.js:3
m.fn.extend.html jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:4
j jquery.min.js:2
k.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
x jquery.min.js:4
b this error msg occured

Comment: @ chandu how can I fix in my localhost